# How to call someone in android?

Tags: android

I am wondering how to call someone in android?

here is my code:

```
setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            String str = getResources().getString(R.string.emergency_number);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(str));
            startActivity(intent);
```

But it doesnt do anything?
Please help?

Comment: What is the value of `R.string.emergency_number`? What does LogCat show?

Comment: startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber)), "Message"));

Answer (score 1):

For using the Dialer application inside your app, you have to do two things.

1. Add the required permission inside your AndroidManifest.xml.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`

2. Launch the Dialer using an Intent

`setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view)  {
        String str = getResources().getString(R.string.emergency_number);
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + str ));
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }
});`

Comment: are you getting exception or error, if you are getting any exception let me know

Comment: no it just doesnt do anything, no errors or expectations just nothing

Comment: btw i am using action_dial instead of action_call

Answer (score 0):

```
btn_dailer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int request_code = 1;
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+mobile_no.trim()));

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            {
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(library_incharge.this,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(library_incharge.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},request_code);
                }
                else
                {
                    startActivity(callIntent);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: When you are adding an answer, don't just add the code. Add relevant text so that  OP can understand your answer clearly.